# Why would I use check() instead of Match.test()?

Tags: javascript, security, meteor

In a production perspective, I do client-side checks (type, length, regex, etc.) on every data field sent to the server using my methods. Of course, I will double check everything on server in the related methods.

Considering that every type or format error case should have been handled by client code, I assume that, on server, it is better to handle errors quietly instead of throwing an explicit error: the data is necessarily coming from a client where original code has been tampered with (if all my clients checks are ok). In practice, I would then use `Match.test()` (quietly) instead of `check()` (error thrown)

Is this a good practice to handle server errors quietly every time it happens on server if this kind of error should have been flagged on client first? If not, why?

Besides, I consider keeping track of these quiet errors and auto-block or flag accounts repeating them more than x times. Is that a good idea?

Comment: Can't assume that any validation has been done client side.

Comment: Please show us some representative code.  We can't really comment on a coding practice without seeing the actual code.  Plus, I think you're asking how you should handle certain types of errors on the server which is entirely application-specific and you've given us no specific context to use to participate in that type of question.  Other than you have to always assume that all data coming from a client may be garbage, there is no general answer, details of error handling and what to do when you find an error are always specific to the situation.

Comment: @charlietfl If I code the client side and add a validation, why wouldn't I assume that this validation should have run? Rather than considering you can't trust client at all, you can consider that a client with a unpredicted behavior is meaningful in terms of security.

Comment: Because the client is completely untrusted.  It can messed with, spoofed or it could even be a non-browser agent someone made up that is talking to your server.  No client data coming from a browser can EVER be trusted.  All data must be verified on your server before doing anything with it.

Comment: You then consider that it is wasting time to track unpredicted behaviors from logged in users? I can update my question with my specific context but to sum it up it is a JS test against a few basic rules on both sides : type, e.g. is string - length e.g. is more than x chars, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are right in that a server should never, ever `throw` an explicit exception on the server without handling it - that will cause your server to crash, and it'll be a nice Denial-Of-Service for everybody.

However, the server should still be able to inform the user if the data is malformed, using a `400` class HTTP error message. Both security and user-friendliness are things that must absolutely be accounted for when dealing with user-inputted data - and with an untrusted client and slow server, both layers should have mechanisms for providing them.